# html5- mp4 video is not supported in all browsers

Tags: html5-video

Mp4 format is not supported by all browsers when using video tag of html5. I googled for the problem and came up with conclusion that i have to convert video into other formats like .ogg .webm etc to run video in all browsers or use plugins.  My question is if i convert one video into three others formats it will occupy more space on the server and i will have huge data on my website and isn't it ridiculous solution to convert one video into three other formats. What is the solution for this problem. does anyone have any idea about this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to reduce video frames bit rate,otherwise we can't.
As per our clients requirement, we need the video to play in all browsers, so we've need to convert to all formats. 
Otherwise compatibility not perfect.
I've worked with HTML5 videos and audios files in many projects. Whether it is so important for compatibility.

**In Video:**

We have to include all video and audio formats like as,".MP4,.webm,.Ogg,.Ogv"

```
<video width="480" height="300" controls="controls" preload="auto" poster="path-to-poster.jpg">
   <source src="path-to-mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="path-to-webm.webm" type="video/webm" />
   <source src="path-to-ogv.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

**In Audio:**

As same as below,

```
 <audio controls preload="none" style="width:480px;">
  <source src="path-to-m4a.m4a" type="audio/mp4" />
  <source src="path-to-oga.oga" type="audio/ogg" />
  <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.</p>
</audio>
```

**Reference:**

1. http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/use-html-5-video-on-all-browsers/
2. http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/how-to-embed-video-using-html5.html#fbid=BmlPj06HFWt